# to copy folders from local machine to folder in server

Tags: c#, asp.net

to copy folders from local machto copy the complete files and folders ,  from local machine , i.e,
folder/directory path which is selected by user has to be completely[all
files within the path is be selected] is to be pasted/copied into 
folder which is in webserver where the web application has been hosted.
ine to folder in server

Comment: Please read this: http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx

Comment: What is your question?  What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I've had quite a difficult time understanding your English. As I understood, your task is to make an exact copy of one folder including all nested folders and files, in some location?
If yes, then I would highly recommend using the console command *xcopy* for that, as it is perfomance-wise optimized and gives the benefit of copying the file-structure with all the related security permissions etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
            string[] SourceFilez = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles("path", "*.*", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories);
            string[] targetFilez = new string[SourceFilez.Length];
            SourceFilez.CopyTo( targetFilez, 0 );


            for(int i = 0; i < targetFilez.Length; ++i)
            {
                targetFilez[i] = targetFilez[i].Replace("oldfolder", "newfolder");

                string strThisDirectory = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(targetFilez[i]);


                if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(strThisDirectory))
                {
                    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(strThisDirectory);
                }

                System.IO.File.Copy(SourceFilez[i], targetFilez[i]);
            }
```

You might want to include the for loop content in a try-catch-finally block.

To account for empty directories, you might want to repeat the same code-block without file.copy, replacing SourceFilez with:

```
string[] SourceDirectories = System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories("path", "*.*", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

If you have IIS7 and the user does not have the necessary permissions to write to the target folder, you need to use identity impersonate and switch the app-pool to classic mode.

**Edit:**
Or do you mean a way to upload all files in a folder on a web-application's user's computer to the server at once ? In that case you need JQuery uploadify:
http://www.uploadify.com/